# Adaptive Bitrate streaming for Audio files with AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, adaptive-bitrate

I want to play audio file from AWS S3 cloud with cloudfront CDN.

Now I want to play audio with adaptive bitrate streaming. I guess, AWS Elastic Transcoder can be used to generate different stream.

**I am having following queries**

1) What should I use among HLS, MPEG-DASH, HDS protocols ?

2) is any of the above protocol is fully supoorted on all browser (FF, Chrome, Safari) and Mobile browsers ?

3) can I use these protocol Directly without any paid media player service like jwplayer?

4) What preset should I use in AWS elastic transcoder? e.g. Audio MP3, HLS Audio etc....

any help will be appreciated. correct me if I am missing something or assuming something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing for so many days, following is my findings.

1) MPEG-DASH

**HLS - HTTP Live Streaming**

```
This protocol is developed by apple and intended for ios/macinstos platform.
```

**HDS - HTTP Dynamic Streaming**

```
This is adobe's method for adaptive bitrate streaming for flash.
```

**MPEG-DASH - Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP**

```
ISO Standard which has the potential to replace existing proprietary technologies like Microsoft Smooth Streaming,Adobe's HDS, Apple's HLS.
So this will be standardize protocol targeted to be used in all compatible devices.
```

**Go for MPEG-DASH**

2) AFAIK **DASH** is not natively supported in ios native or mac systems

3) there is a open source project **dash.js** which is based on MediaSource Extension API . using that one can create his/her own customize media player.

4) as far as **DASH** is concerned, one has to create MPEG-DASH audio preset.

let me know if anything is misunderstood.